# Choice of Ubuntu or Ubuntu LTS for Virtualmin Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

My VPS provider currently offers several versions of Ubuntu.  They offer from 10.04 to 11.10 (which only 10.04 is LTS).  I would not like to wait for them to get the 12.04 LTS version out.  Should I opt for a newer version of Ubuntu like 11.10?  Or go with the 10.04 LTS?  This will be a public web server running Virtualmin.  Would the only difference be newer packages?  Is 10.04 "more" secure since it has been around longer to patch security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1):

If 10.04 server edition has the packages you want then I would choose that since it will receive security updates until 2015.  11.10 will stop receiving updates next year, so you would be upgrading to something else in less than 12 months.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: In [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/timeline/370c55d1688f99fce74136661c08c372.png) image you can see when the end of life will be for the different versions.

Answer (score 1):

10.04 will be stable for a longer time, they are (arguably) equally secure.

The decision is this, if you are going to keep this server around for a number of years, you should use 10.04.  If you plan on rebuilding it when 12.04 comes out then I would go with the more recent 11.10 because there will be less major changes between packages.